# Python tkinter passing input value within the same class

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Most of the code below is just so the problem is accurately replicated, the issue most likely is in the hand-off of `filename` from`askopenfilenameI()` to `printing(stringToPrint)`or the `if` statement at the end.

### Goal

The goal of this program is to simply print the file path to the console when `Print File Path` button is clicked.

### Current state

When the program is executed the window appears correctly and the it lets you select a file in the file system. Once the file is opened, the script seems to call `printing` method before it executes its own `print` statement. When I open another file it prints the only the print statement from `askopenfilename()` (which is correct).

However, clicking the `Print File Path` Button does not seem to get work at any stage.

An example output would be:

Value on click: `no-file`

askopenfilename value: `C:/Temp/AFTER_FIRST_OPEN.txt`

askopenfilename value: `C:/Temp/AFTER_SECOND_OPEN.txt`

### Code

```
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

filename = 'no-file'

class TkApp(Tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):

        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)
    
        # options for buttons
        button_opt = {'fill': Tkconstants.BOTH, 'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
    
        # define buttons
        Tkinter.Button(self, text='Open File', command=self.askopenfilename).pack(**button_opt)
        Tkinter.Button(self, text='Print File Path', command=self.printing(filename)).pack(**button_opt)
        Tkinter.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit).pack(**button_opt)
         
        # define options for opening or saving a file
        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.twb'
        options['filetypes'] = [('All', '*')]
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
        options['parent'] = root
        options['title'] = 'Select a File'

    def askopenfilename(self):
        """Returns an opened file in read mode.
        This time the dialog just returns a filename and the file is opened by your own code.
        """
        global filename        
        # get filename
        filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
    
        # open file on your own
        if filename:
            print "askopenfilename value: " + filename
            return filename
            
    def printing(self, stringToPrint):
        print "Value on click: " + stringToPrint
   
    def quit(self):
        root.destroy()
        
 if __name__=='__main__':
        root = Tkinter.Tk()
        root.title("Path Printer")  
        TkApp(root).pack()
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `command=self.printing(filename)` argument is actually calling the `printing()` function as the "Print File Path" Button is being defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you're calling `self.printing` at the time you create the button. The solution is simple: change `self.printing(filename)` to be just `self.printing`, and then have `self.printing` print an attribute that is set by `self.askopenfilename`.

For example:

```
class TkApp(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        ...
        self.currentFile = None
        ...
        Tkinter.Button(self, text='Open File', command=self.askopenfilename)
        Tkinter.Button(self, text='Print File Path', command=self.printing)
        ...

    def askopenfilename(self):
        ...
        self.currentFile = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
        ...

    def printing(self):
        print "Value on click: " + self.currentFile
```

Note: a `return` statement in a function that is called from a button serves absolutely no purpose. The actual caller of the button ignores all return values.

Comment: Thanks a ton Bryan! So just to understand this for next time, the function does not have to "return" a value in order to be picked up by another function? Is it enough to define a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the `self.printing` function cannot take arguments when called from a button press. This is common in many GUI libraries. To get around this, I would recommend that you change `filename` to `self.filename`, so that it can be called from `self.printing` even if it isn't passed.

The code would be:

```
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
class TkApp(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        # options for buttons
        button_opt = {'fill': Tkconstants.BOTH, 'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        #moved initiation of filename to here so it will print if no file has been selected
        self.filename = 'no-file'
        # define buttons
        Tkinter.Button(self, text='Open File', command=self.askopenfilename).pack(**button_opt)
        Tkinter.Button(self, text='Print File Path', command=self.printing).pack(**button_opt) #not the removal of variable.
        Tkinter.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit).pack(**button_opt)

        # define options for opening or saving a file
        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.twb'
        options['filetypes'] = [('All', '*')]
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
        options['parent'] = root
        options['title'] = 'Select a File'

    def askopenfilename(self):
        """Returns an opened file in read mode.
        This time the dialog just returns a filename and the file is opened by your own code.
        """       
        # get filename - edited to be part of self
        self.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)

        # open file on your own
        if self.filename:
            print "askopenfilename value: " + self.filename
            return self.filename

    def printing(self):
        print "Value on click: " + self.filename

    def quit(self):
        root.destroy()

if __name__=='__main__':
        root = Tkinter.Tk()
        root.title("Path Printer")  
        TkApp(root).pack()
        root.mainloop()
```